Snap wire-like object on curve surface

Blender 4.1. There are two objects: a cup and a wire-like ornament. I have to put the ornament on surface of the cup, as if it was soldered. I can not find a way to make ornament follow the curve of the base object.

Maybe use a Displace modifier on your cup to create the ornment (the cup needs to be subdivided enough) and apply the modifier?
